# Grails - Multiple Datasources

Tags: grails, oracle11g, multiple-databases, multi-tenant

First, let me start that I have looked so many sites about the "correct" way to configure multiple datasource on Grails, every one of them (with Grails 2.0 and later) pointing to the  [docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/single.html#multipleDatasources) , however after doing what the docs says I get this error:

```
Error 2014-03-29 15:48:29,219 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader      - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager_lookup': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory_lookup' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory_lookup': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean '$primaryTransactionManager' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '$primaryTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager_lookup': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory_lookup' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory_lookup': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean '$primaryTransactionManager' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '$primaryTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable   circular reference?
```

What I find most interesting is that if I specify:

```
dataSource_lookup
```

I will get:

```
Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name     'transactionManager_lookup'
```

And if I change it to:

```
dataSource_mysqldb
```

I get:

```
Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager_mysqldb'
```

If I don't specify a second datasource, everything works just fine.

My code:

```
dataSource {
 logSql = true
 pooled = true
 dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
 driverClassName = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
 username = 'myuser'
 password = 'mypass'
 url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase'
 dbCreate = 'update'
}

dataSource_mysql {
 dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
 driverClassName = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
 username = 'myuser'
 password = 'mypass'
 url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase'
 dbCreate = 'update'
}

dataSource_oracle {
 dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
 driverClassName = 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
 username = 'myuser'
 password = 'mypass'
 url = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:mydatabase'
 dbCreate = 'update'
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? (As stated before, if I eliminate the two secondary dataSources (dataSource_mysql and dataSource_oracle) everything works just fine).

Thanks in advance.
Dev: Ubuntu - Grails 2.3.7 - MySQL - Oracle 11g.

Comment: If default `dataSource` is pointing to the same db in MySql, why do you need `dataSource_mysql`? As I see on first glance, two dataSources beans tried to be created by container pointing to same db with same credentials, therefore the circular reference error. Remove `dataSource_mysql`, only use datasource (default) and `dataSource_oracle`.

Comment: Facing similar problem in grails 2.3.6 and grails 2.3.7, but wirking fine in grails 2.3.5

Comment: Thanks dmahapatro for your recomendation, with it my code has been optimized, however, I still get the same error and furthermore if I change the oracle block to a mysql one (this is one dataSource(default) and one dataSource_mysql but with different databases and different servers) I get the same error, so is not a mysql-oracle issue. Any other ideas? Does somebody has this working on Grails 2.3.7?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Trying to define a mysql and oracle datasource in Grails 2.3.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I figured this out.

In the Grails 2.3.7 release notes it says to upgrade your hibernate version. I failed to do that.

http://grails.org/2.3.7+Release+Notes

`runtime ':hibernate:3.6.10.10'`

Then after I did that I stopped getting that error and got another error

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: null
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at ....MigrationUtils.createInstance(MigrationUtils.groovy:220)
    at ....MigrationUtils.getDatabase(MigrationUtils.groovy:57)
    at ....MigrationUtils.getDatabase(MigrationUtils.groovy:116)
    at DbmGenerateGormChangelog$_...doCall(DbmGenerateGormChangelog:52)
    at ....MigrationUtils.executeInSession(MigrationUtils.groovy:132)
    at DbmGenerateGormChangelog$_run_closure2.doCall(DbmGenerateGormChangelog:51)
    at DbmGenerateGormChangelog$_run_closure1.doCall(DbmGenerateGormChangelog:33)`

I've never had to specify the hibernate dialect for oracle before, but apparently in the most recent version of the migrations plugin (1.3.8 currently), you have to.

```
dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
```

I was already specifying the dialect for MySQL so I don't know if it would produce the same error if removed.

Comment: While I haven't had time to confirm this, I have read the docs and looks like with the hibernate upgrade it might work. Looking forward to confirm this.