# Grails 2.4.4 with multiple dataSources

Tags: hibernate, grails

I am having issues running an application with multiple dataSources using Grails 2.4.4.  It is a very similar problem that was posted here: ([Grails - Multiple Datasources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737532/grails-multiple-datasources)), although the solution is for Grails 2.3.7.

I looked at the [Grails Software Release](https://grails.org/wiki/Releases) notes since 2.3.7, and most of them recommended upgrading tomcat and hibernate (not specifically for this error).  Using the recommended versions of hibernate and tomcat or downgrading back to the 2.3.7 configurations still generates this error.  Does anyone know how to get around this?

```
2015-09-23 15:50:50,975 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor':
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean
'transactionManager_orcl' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager_orcl': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory_orcl' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory_orcl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager_orcl' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager_orcl': Cannot resolve reference to bean
'sessionFactory_orcl' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory_orcl': Invocation of init
method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]  

    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager_orcl' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager_orcl': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory_orcl' while setting bean property
'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory_orcl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager_orcl': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory_orcl' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory_orcl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory_orcl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by CacheException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another unnamed CacheManager already exists in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name.
The source of the existing CacheManager is: DefaultConfigurationSource [ ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml ]
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by CacheException: Another unnamed CacheManager already exists in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name.
The source of the existing CacheManager is: DefaultConfigurationSource [ ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml ]
->>  628 | assertNoCacheManagerExistsWithSameName in net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    392 | init      in     ''
|    270 | <init> .  in     ''
|    262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.vendor="Sun Microsystems Inc."
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with errorPicked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.vendor="Sun Microsystems Inc."
```

Comment: `Caused by CacheException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another unnamed CacheManager already exists in the same VM` looks like it's the real issue

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up @BurtBeckwith ... that got me on the right trail.  It turned out to be more related to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31524547/grails-2-5-another-unnamed-cachemanager-already-exists-in-the-same-vm-when-us .  I believe the OP got his solution from the Grails 2.5.0 Update Notes here https://github.com/grails/grails-core/releases/tag/v2.5.0 .